# C# Libraries for CouchDB?

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb

I haven't seen the question asked/answered for over a year, and I'm sure there have a been a lot of changes in that time.

If you are using CouchDB in a .Net/C# environment (in production), I'd like to know which library you use, and what your experiences with it have been.

I have found that there are at least four libraries out there: Hammock, Relax, Divan, and SharpCouch.  However, I find very little in the way of tutorials, blog posts, testimonials, documentation etc. when I google their names + "CouchDB".  It also seems that none of them has a binary release yet (all "pull the source and build").

Are these libraries still pretty new/immature?  Are they so simple that there's no real need for documentation?  Are so few .Net developers using CouchDB that no one is talking about it in that space?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CouchDB functionality is exposed through HTTP API, so all you actually need is a good HTTP library and some error code handling. I guess that's the reason you'll not find many CouchDB libs around: the protocol/API is so easy that you can get started right away.

Answer (score 1):

I develop .Net and Java. In .Net I really didn't find anything like the one I used in Java to access couchDb. There in java, I used a library called jkniv which is more of a lightweight ORM that allows me to map the same domain to relational DBMS's, NoSQL and also Cassandra, changing only the querie files that are stored in one or more XML files with dynamic parse of the content.

I looked for something in .net something similar that facilitates the use of couchDb but I did not find it, they were all as you mentioned, download and compile yours ... this does not please me very much.

So, for a personal application project, **I ended up taking inspiration from jkniv and *created* a library *myself*** that simplifies the use of couchDb without having to handle http requests in my code directly. It encapsulates the handling of HTTP requests and even allows me to separate couchDb's "find" commands to make my C # code, leaving it cleaner and easier to understand and maintain.

What's more, the XML files where I place these commands contain dynamic syntax based on attribute values ​​where I can decide whether to add snippets to the command based on logical tests. Example: If the "IsFemale" attribute of the "Person" object is equal to true, add a mango-querie snippet to the "find" command that will be sent to couchDb.

In addition, these commands allow you to use text parses based on attributes of the parameter object. Example: the command {"selector": {"name": {"$ regex" :: filter}} will have the parameter ": filter" replaced by the value of this property of the passed parameter.

The advantage is that this library is just a facilitator, the "find" and "view" commands use couchDb's native syntax, so you build your querie there on couchDb itself, test it and if it's the way you want it, just fill it out it in the XML file, giving an id and referencing this id in your C # code.

Ah, the library is already compiled and installed via Nuget.

Below are some examples of how to example it. The detailed explanation of how to configure and use it is on [Github](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository/blob/master/doc.pdf).

Link: [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CouchDb.Repository.Helper/) |
[Github](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository) | [Example of use](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository/tree/master/samples/Apache.Couchdb.Helper.Sample)

Example of the class that represents a document. Must be inherit from AbstractDocument:

```
public enum DocType
{
    USER,
    GROUP
}

public enum Status
{
    PRE_ACTIVE, ACTIVE, INACTIVE, LOCKED, PRE_CANCEL, CANCEL
}

/// <summary>
/// The objects that represent a document must inherit from AbstractDocument 
/// and set the generic to the type of the object itself. With this, this 
/// object must not contain the "_id" and "_rev" properties since the inherited 
/// class contains these implementations and the services related to these 
/// two attributes.
/// Only the methods mapped with [JsonProperty] attribute will be persisted in the 
/// document as well as read and filled in automatically.
/// </summary>
public class User: AbstractDocument<User>
{

    [JsonProperty("sourceId")] //Newtonsoft
    public String SourceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ownerId")] //Newtonsoft
    public String OwnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")] //Newtonsoft
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")] //Newtonsoft
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("acctId")] //Newtonsoft
    public String AcctId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("docType")] //Newtonsoft
    public DocType DocType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")] //Newtonsoft
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("assetIam")] //Newtonsoft
    public String AssetIam { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("serial")] //Newtonsoft
    public String Serial { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"User data: [SourceID: {SourceId}, OwnerID: {OwnerId}, Name: {Name}, Email: {Email}. AcctId: {AcctId}, docType: {DocType} Type: {TypeDocument}, Status: {Status}, AssetIam: {AssetIam}, Serial: {Serial}]";
    }

}
```

Create a class that represents the database, extending the CouchRepository class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a repository to represent the database informed
/// in context.Extend the CouchDb Helper repository and tell 
/// the constructor what context will be used for this created repository.
/// </summary>
public class UserRepository: CouchRepository
{
    public UserRepository() : base("users-db") { } //users-db is context name defined in appsettings.json
}
```

Example of adding documents:

```
User user = createUser("email@email.com");
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    var result = db.Insert<User>(user); // add document and return instance changed with operation revision id
    Console.WriteLine(result.Revision);
}
```

Example of changing documents:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    // Load document data by ID
    var user = db.Get<User>("email@email.com");
    user.Name = user.Name + "::CHANGED";

    var result = db.Update<User>(user); // update document and return instance changed with operation revision id
    Console.WriteLine(result.Revision);
}
```

Example of deleting documents:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    // Load document data by ID
    var user = db.Get<User>("email@email.com");

    var result = db.Delete<User>(user); // delete document from database. Return true case sucess or false case not deleted
    Console.WriteLine($"Sucesso: {result}");
}
```

Example of select documents collections:

```
var sts = new List<String> { "ACTIVE", "LOCKED" }; // param filter
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository())
{
    var query = db.FindOf("list-status", new { id = "OwnerIdloop.user.7", statuses = sts, filterStatus = true});
    var users = db.List<User>(query);
}
```

The find command written in the xml used in the code above through the identifier "list-status" is:

```
    <find id="list-status">
    {
      "selector": {
      "$and": [
          {
          "docType": {"$eq": "USER"},
          "ownerId": {"$eq": :id }
          <if test="filterStatus == true">
            , "status": {"$in": :in:statuses }
          </if>
          }        
       ]
      },
      "fields": [ "_id", "_rev", "ownerId", "sourceId", "docType", "name", "email","status","acctId","assetIam","serial"]
    }
</find>
```

Get all documents of a Type:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository()){
    /* The document must contain the 'typeDoc' attribute with the same value as the type entered. */
    users = db.GetAllOf<User>(); //Get all doc from type parametized.
}
```

Get one documento by id:

```
using (UserRepository db = new UserRepository()){
    // Load document data by ID
    var user = db.Get<User>("email@email.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be some like!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sDireccion = @"http://localhost:5984/base_principal/_all_docs";
        var client = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("zzz", "zzz + zzz"), Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        var sRespuesta = client.DownloadString(sDireccion);
        cClaseBase cBase = new cClaseBase();
        cBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cClaseBase>(sRespuesta);
        foreach (Row str in cBase.rows)
        {
            sDireccion = @"http://localhost:5984/base_principal/"+str.id;
            sRespuesta = client.DownloadString(sDireccion);
            cClaseDetalle cd = new cClaseDetalle();
            cd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cClaseDetalle>(sRespuesta);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I have a library that uses LINQ to query CouchDB like EF Core.

It's pretty mature at this point.

https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/couchdb-net